# ESX or ESXi as FCoE or ISCSI or NFS target?

Tags: storage, vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, nfs, iscsi

Is is possible to set up ESXi or more expensive ESX server as a storage target (FCoE, ISCSI or NFS, in that order) for other ESX servers? If so, how?

Comment: ESX is to my knowledge not more pricey.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution would be to set up a VM guest on the ESX / ESXi server running something like openfiler which is a linux based open source storage server

It can be downloaded from http://www.openfiler.com/ and supports iSCSI and NFS - not sure about FCoE

Comment: FCoE isn't quite there yet, but OpenFiler will get it pretty soon (within 18 months is my guess).

Comment: Interesting solution. But seems like a lot of overhead.

Comment: Would it be possible set up ISCSI target on ESX(i)

Answer (score 1):

You can install [Openfiler](http://www.openfiler.com/community/download) or FreeNAS or similar project and pass whole physical hard drive(s) to this virtual machine (VMWare Raw Disk Mapping - RDM). Then you can easily configure Openfiler as FCoE Target or iSCSI target or NFS Server.

[image]
You can configure your ESXi manually.

Example:

```
vmkfstools -r /vmfs/devices/disks/vml.01000000002020202020205354463630374d473356304a554b486974616368 testdisk_1.vmdk
```

and then edited the servername.vmx to include the following lines:

```
scsi0:1.present = TRUE
scsi0:1.fileName = /vmfs/volumes/datastore2/DC1/testdisk_1.vmdk
```

[Discussion](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?p=2084653#p2084653) about VMWare Raw Disk Mapping, and similar [questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/180310/access-a-physical-drive-in-a-ubuntu-vm-on-esx-4) at ServerFault.

Here is complete [HOWTO](http://www.techhead.co.uk/how-to-configure-openfiler-v23-iscsi-storage-for-use-with-vmware-esx) configuration Openfiler as iSCSI target for ESX/ESXi.